# What are the specific words to describe lines/wrinkles/crinkles on a piece of paper or a book?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, image-identification, books

Are there any specific words to describe such things? Is it minor damages, wrinkles, marks, creases? Not a fold and I don't mean the crumpled ones that most people do before throwing to the trashcan, but the small lines that you get when you don't carefully carry.

[image]

Comment: "Creases" would work.

Comment: I'm sure the folks who deal with antique books and the like have very precise terms, but most people would simply call them  "wrinkles".

Comment: Please consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better.

Comment: [Shop-soiled](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shop-soiled) comes close, but may be too generic.

Answer (score 2):

[Crease](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crease)

> a line on cloth or paper where it has been folded or crushed:

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is the right answer. Ideally, answers should answer the question as an expert would, with explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Creases is the correct word to use here

Definition number 1 of "crease" in Chambers dictionary: a mark made by folding, pressing or crumpling. Which refers to what you have asked. Also, I have never, in my 30 years of living in English speaking countries, heard another native English speaker use anything other than "creases" to describe what I see in the picture. Hope this helps.

Comment: Avoid adding filler to pad an answer to the minimum length. It defeats the purpose of this site. Answers are expected to be lengthy. A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.

Comment: Apologies. Definition number 1 of "crease" in Chambers dictionary: a mark made by folding, pressing or crumpling. Which refers to that asked by the asker. Also, I have never, in my 30 years of living in English speaking countries, heard another native English speaker use anything other than "creases" to describe what I see in the picture. Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. Can you [edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/448185/edit) your answer to incorporate the new information?